# Definition of image

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The image of a relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ is defined as $C = \{ b \in B : \exists a \in A \space (a, b) \in R \}$, which is equivalent to $\forall b [b \in C \leftrightarrow b \in B \space \land \exists a \in A (a, b) \in R]$. In case of a function $f : A \rightarrow B$, the image of $f$ can be alternatively defined as $C = \{f(a) : a \in A \}$. How do I translate this definition to predicate logic? $\forall b [b \in C \leftrightarrow b = f(a) \land a \in A]$ **OR** $\forall b [b \in C \leftrightarrow \exists a \in A \space b = f(a)]$? Either way, how can I derive this last definition from the general one?

Comment: Hint: A function $f:A\to B$ is a relation $f$ from $A$ to $B$ such that (1) For each $a\in A$ there exists $(a,b)\in f$ and (2) If $(a,b_1)\in f$,  $(a,b_2)\in f$  then $b_1=b_2$.

Comment: And that means that the variable $a$ is existentially quantified in $C = \{ f(a) : a \in A \}$? I can't see a way to describe the range without existential quantification.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The image of $f$ is the set defined by $\forall b [b \in C \leftrightarrow b \in B \space \land \exists a \in A (a, b) \in f]$.

Comment: Yes, but this statement means $C = \{ b \in B : \exists a \in A \space (a, b) \in f \}$, not $C = \{f(a) : a \in A \}$. I would like to know how to translate the latter to predicate logic.

Comment: You have that, for a *function* $f$:  $f(a)=y \leftrightarrow (a,y) \in f$. Thus, $C = \{ f/a) \mid a \in A \} = \{ y \mid a \in A \land (a,y) \in f \}$. This in turn implies: $z \in C \leftrightarrow \exists a (a \in A \land (a,z) \in f \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $\forall b\left[b\in C \leftrightarrow \exists a\in A\left(b = f(a)\right)\right]$ if and only if $C = \left\{f(a): a\in A\right\}$

> $\forall b\left[b\in C\leftrightarrow b=f(a)\wedge a\in A\right]$ OR $\forall b\left[b\in C\leftrightarrow\exists a\in A \left(b=f(a)\right)\right]$

Problem here is, the first one is not a sentence, i.e. there is a free variable $a$.

Comment: If $C = \left\{f(a): a\in A\right\}$ is equivalent to $\forall b\left[b\in C \leftrightarrow \exists a\in A\left(b = f(a)\right)\right]$, then we could expend the following reasoning. Suppose $\forall b[b\in C \leftrightarrow \exists a\in A b = f(a)]$. By universal instantiation, let $f(a_0) \in C \leftrightarrow \exists a\in A f(a_0) = f(a)$, considering $a_0 \in A$. Now, why does one say that $f(a_0) \in C \rightarrow a_0 \in A$? This last implication does not derive from $f(a_0) \in C \leftrightarrow \exists a\in A f(a_0) = f(a)$.

Comment: It comes from the definition of $f$. Think $f$ as a subset of $A\times B$. If there is an $f(a_0)$, it means that there is a unique $b\in B$ such that $(a_0, b)\in f\subseteq A\times B$, hence $a_0\in A$